# not able to read from resource in robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I am trying to write robolectric test for android app. when i am trying to read the cofig, i am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Got resource name bool/config_enable from id 2131427329 (0x7f0b0001), but found no resource by that name
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.BoolResourceLoader.getValue(BoolResourceLoader.java:27)
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.getBooleanValue(ResourceLoader.java:462)
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getBoolean(ShadowResources.java:193)
at android.content.res.Resources.getBoolean(Resources.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/346. Which version of Robolectric are you using? I guess this was only ever fixed in Robolectric 2...